# Regular user can't use slash commands

Tags: discord.js

I am currently working on my discord bot. While I was testing commands everything was going well until I ran to a problem. Slash commands can only be used by admins. I though it was permission issue and it was - `@everyone` had no permission to use slash commands. Also, it didn't work. I can send code if anyone have idea of what can cause such a problem.

Stright to the point - I want to give every user possibility to use slash commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your code and the settings of your Discord server this problem will be difficult to identify.

But there are 2 things that I can think of that might cause this.

1. The @everyone role does not have the permissions to use so called application commands. This is changed in Discord itself
2. You check for a specific role or permission somewhere in your code that prevents any further execution (I don't know your code, but this could be a possible cause of your problem).

Obviously there are more reasons that can cause this problem, but I'd say these are the most likely ones.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/C0dagon/GeekOn) Here is the code on github. I don't know where can be specific problem so there you have it all. Only thing missing is config file. I had already tried to change permissions to roles on discord itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it was a setting in the server,
about the bot integrations. Manage your bot and then ROLES&MEMBERS.
Put @everyone on true and it was fixed.

Hope I can help people in the further now